# Wysiwyg cant detect CKEditor

Tags: javascript, drupal, ckeditor, drupal-modules, wysiwyg

I am downloading modules on Drupal, but I am having trouble with Wysiwyg. It says it needs an editor library, so I downloaded the CKEditor module, which works just fine. When I go into Wysiwyg configuration, however, it keeps telling my that "The version of *CKEditor* could not be detected. It then says that I should extract the contents so that the library can be found at:

sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js

I did exactly that, I reset the permissions, I have looked at different installation guides, but nothing seems to work. Do any of you guys know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version of CKEditor, which is version 4, you need to edit the WYSIWYG module of Drupal. The module verifies the editor version using a regular expression which doesn't match with version definition (in javascript) of CKEditor.

You need to modify the `wysiwyg/editors/ckeditor.inc` file from line 77 to 88 (basically the `while` loop) with this modified code:

```
while ($max_lines && $line = fgets($library, 500)) {
  // version:'CKEditor 3.0 SVN',revision:'3665'
  // version:'3.0 RC',revision:'3753'
  // version:'3.0.1',revision:'4391'
  if (preg_match('@version:\"(?:CKEditor )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:\"([\d]+))?@', $line, $version)) {
    fclose($library);
    // Version numbers need to have three parts since 3.0.1.
    $version[1] = preg_replace('/^(\d+)\.(\d+)$/', '${1}.${2}.0', $version[1]);
    return $version[1] . ((isset($version[2])) ? '.' . $version[2] : '');
  }
  $max_lines--;
}
```

Single quotes has been changed to double quotes in regular expression + the return value adds an extra `isset` condition.